# MemoryError raised when calling a python function that generates millions of data

Tags: python, memory-management

My code is dependent on a function in python module stored somewhere on an AFS system, this function returns a list with millions of data and whenever I try assigning the results of this function to a variable a MemoryError is raised, I wish I could rewrite this function to write its output to a csv file but I'm not allowed to change the implementation of this function, is there anyway to get the output of this function without getting a MemoryError and changing the implementation of the function.

```
from afs_module import get_data

output_data = []

output_data = get_data()
```

Comment: You are not allowed to change the code but are you allowed to allocate more memory to the machine running the code ?

Comment: not really, this code may be deployed in several places where we don't have the right to allocate more memory

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: We cannot change the code and we have no control over the machine configuration. Hard to change if no change is allowed. :(

Comment: the only code we can't change is the get_data fucntion, Is there a way to store the output of get_data() directly into a file and processing it in chunks?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `MemoryError` happens **during** the execution of `get_data`, which you can’t modify, because of system memory constraints that you also can’t modify, this is impossible.  It’s not the assignment that’s at fault—you’re not calling `list` on a generator, for instance—so there’s nothing to change here.